# MATLAB - replace zeros in matrix with small number

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with some elements going to zero. This is a problem for me in consequent operations (taking log, etc). Is there a way to quickly replace zero elements in a matrix with a input of my choice. Quickly - meaning, without a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure--where A is your matrix,

```
A(A==0) = my_small_number;
```

Answer (score 5):

The direct answer is:

```
M(M == 0) = realmin;
```

which does exactly what you ask for, replacing zeros with a small number. See that this does an implicit search for the zeros in a vectorized way. No loops are required. (This is a MATLAB way, avoiding those explicit and slow loops.)

Or, you could use max, since negative numbers are never an issue. So

```
M = max(M,realmin);
```

will also work. Again, this is a vectorized solution. I'm not positive which one is faster without a careful test, but either will surely be acceptable.

Note that I've used realmin here instead of eps, since it is as small as you can realistically get in a double precision number. But use whatever small number makes sense to you.

```
log10(realmin)
ans =
 -307.6527
```

Compare that to eps.

```
log10(eps)
ans =
  -15.6536
```

Comment: `-realmax` and `-Inf` are a lot smaller. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Assume your matrix is called `A`

```
A(A==0) = eps;
```